# repos.key missing the release key?

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ros-crystal, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the directions [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Linux-Install-Debians/) to install ROS2 Crystal on Ubuntu 18.04. I've just done the `curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -` step, but when I follow that up with `apt-get update`, I get a warning that the signatures couldn't be verified (`NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116`). Sure enough, that key is not downloaded in the `curl` step, according to the output of `apt-key list`. This has definitely worked for me in the past - did the key change or something like that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324350/repos.key-missing-the-release-key?/) by [creffett](https://answers.ros.org/users/41930/creffett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this was already reported in [ros2/ros2#713](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/713).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [creffett](https://answers.ros.org/users/41930/creffett/) on 2019-05-30**:
Ah, so it was. Thanks!